# Angular : ng-include does not work when i run my app locally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am currently building a small app in Angular. I am using ng-include and calling a very simple partials by doing e.g :

`<div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"> </div>`

When i load the page through live-server I am getting "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost" on each of the partials I am doing. This is very weird since the path is correct and i am including the path in the ng-include directive in single quotes. When i paste all my code on plunker, everything works fine. Did any one encounter this in the past? Any solutions?

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with whatever server you have that is supposed to be serving the partials.

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server at the moment.

Comment: Just used http-server instead of live-server and it worked just fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I was using live-server from npm which apparently has a problem with loading partials. I now switched over to http-server and it's working fine. Thanks Explosion Pills for the